# Spring return dynamic instance based of String value

Tags: spring, dynamic, instance

Java Spring question:

I have a interface MyInterface with one method 
void exec (String str);

I have many implementation of MyInterface,  say Oneimpl, anotherimpl yetanotherimpl...and so on and can keep adding new implementations.

how do I obtain an instance of a specific implementation using just the name of the implementing class passed as a STRING value , say "someRandomImpl"

The code should be dynamic and can provide a instance of new implementations without code change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implements ApplicationContextAware
it will autowired ApplicationContext object
use the object like

```
context.getBean(beanName)
```

then you get the bean